# $K(G) \leq K(G-e)$ $K(G)$ is domination number of $G$ $ K(G-e)$ is domination number of $G$

Tags: graph-theory

prove thath $K(G) \leq K(G-e)$.

$K(G)$ is domination number of $G$

$ K(G-e)$ is domination number of $G$

$e$ is an edge of $G$

Comment: tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Consider any dominating set $D$ of $G - e$. Then for all $v \in V(G-e)$, $v \not \in D$, $v$ is adjacent to some vertex in $D$.

As $V(G-e) = V(G)$, and adding an edge doesn't change any of the previous adjacency claims, then $D$ is a dominating set of $G$. Since $D$ was arbitrary the claim follows.